# Question about selecting data frame rows based on partial string match in a column

Tags: r, stringr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlWIq.png)I'm wondering why after running this code I can't detect anything in my dataset?
Is there any wrong with my code or the dataset?
Thanks!

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data1<-uoe_art%>% filter(str_detect(title, "child"))
head(data1)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share reproducible example of your data using dput()

Comment: maybe I can upload my markdown document here?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the output of: `head(uoe_art)`

Comment: Did you pay attention to the case ? Because R does ..